# Jquery Mobile select box onchange redirect is not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using latest version of jquery mobile (1.3.1)
There is  a language select box on page. I need to redirect the page when new language is selected
I used below code for this

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" data-native-menu='false' name="lang" id='lang'>
<option value='home.php?&lang=en' >English</option>
<option value='home.php?&lang=pr' >Portuguese</option>
<option value='home.php?&lang=it' >Italian</option>
</select>
```

But page is not redirected when a new option is selected.
This was working in older version of jquery mobile (1.0.6)
Is something missing? Please help

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/F7vCJ/

Comment: It is working like charm. Thanks a lot for help..

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help :)

Comment: More info and options http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.mobile.changePage()` in this case.

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
 var lang = $(this).val();
 $.mobile.changePage(lang);
});
```

> Reference: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/